# Sharing variables between .py and .kv files, also loading and saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.6

I'm making a text based game, which is pretty much fully completed on python. I have a saving and loading system, and it is a fluently running game, however, i wanted to make a GUI to make it more user friendly. I decided to use kivy. I have worked out how to use screens, and switch between screens (basically I have the graphical side of things worked out) but I want to be able to use variables in my app and save progress to various files. For example:

I have a button. By pressing the button, let's say the 'ego' stat goes up by 1. I have the ego stat in my .py file like so:

```
presentation = Builder.load_file("Baller.kv") #loads the .kv file I am using
class BallerApp(App):
    ego = 0 #here the ego stat is set to 0
    def build(self):
        return presentation
```

Now say I want to add 1 to that variable while running the program (I am assuming I will need something like 'on_release: ego = ego + 1') and save the ego variable as 1 while the app is running. Then at a pre-determined save point in my game, I want to export this 'ego' variable as the number 1 to a file called 'stats.txt', how would I do that?

Lastly, when the app is opened you are greeted with this home menu:

[image]

How would I load the stats when the 'Load Game' button is pressed (in this case, just the ego variable) into my kivy application? I know how to do it in a regular python program, but how would I get the variables to change while the app is running?

Thank you in advance for any help I receive on this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the example below.

**main.py**

```
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    ego_stat = NumericProperty(0)

    def update_ego_stat(self):
        self.ego_stat += 1

    def save_ego_stat(self):
        with open("ego_stat.txt", "w") as fobj:
            fobj.write(str(self.ego_stat))

    def load_ego_stat(self):
        with open("ego_stat.txt") as fobj:
            for stat in fobj:
                self.ego_stat = int(stat.rstrip())


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        id: lbl_wid
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.ego_stat)
    Button:
        text: "ego stat"
        on_release: root.update_ego_stat()
    Button:
        text: "save ego stat"
        on_release: root.save_ego_stat()
    Button:
        text: "Load Game"
        on_release: root.load_ego_stat()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much bro, been trying to figure this out ALL DAY.

Comment: Worked perfectly :)